# Extracting pattern count and dumping them into array

Tags: javascript

My program currently loops through an array and counts the amount of times a pattern occurs in all of them together.

For example: if I should search "**at**" at prompt I will end up with:

```
0,1,2,3,4
```

But really I want to end up with

```
4,1
```

As **at** appears 4 times in array 1 and once in array 2.

This being the amount of times the pattern occurs in the array.

Any advice on how I can achieve this?

Many thanks in advance!

```
web = ["cat fat hat mat", "that the who"];

var search = prompt('Search?');

function count(web, pattern)
{
    if (pattern)
    {
        var num = 0;
        var result = [];
        for (i = 0; i < web.length; i++)
        {
            var current = web[i];
            var index = current.indexOf(pattern);
            while (index >= 0)
            {
                result[result.length] = num++;
                index = current.indexOf(pattern, index + 1);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
    else
    {
        return ("Nothing entered!");
    }
}
alert(count(web, search));
```

Comment: I am utterly lost with your question. You initially search for "at" in where? why do you end up getting 0,1,2,3,4? and you have a list of patters(or I assume) ["cat fat hat mat", "that the who"] and what are you searching for? Can you elaborate a little?

Comment: I would like to return the count of a recurring pattern and return it within an array.

Comment: I am sorry I am not able to get you. Can you provide some example? the example "at" just doesn't seem to be complete.

Comment: Hey sorry about this: I've updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var web = ["cat fat hat mat", "that the who"];

var search = prompt('Search?');

function count(web, pattern)
{
    if (pattern)
    {
        var num = 0;
        var result = [];
        for (i = 0; i < web.length; i++)
        {
            var current = web[i];
            var index = 0;
            do{
                result[i] = num++;
                index = current.indexOf(pattern, index + 1);

            }while (index >= 0)
            num = 0;
        }
        return result;
    }
    else
    {
        return ("Nothing entered!");
    }
}
alert(count(web, search));
```

This works too

```
var web = ["cat fat hat mat", "th the who"];

var answer = prompt('Search?');
var search = new RegExp( answer, "g");

function count(web, pattern)
{
    var result = [];
    for(var i=0; i< web.length; i++){
        var matches = web[i].match(search) || [];
        result[i] = matches.length;
    }

    return result.join(",");
}
alert(count(web, search));
```

Comment: that is regular expression function which finds how much times that expression occurred in string and it returns array of those occurrences

Answer (score 0):

```
var s = prompt('Search?');
var web = ["cat fat hat mat", "that the who"];
function count(search,arr){
 var reg = new RegExp(search,'g');
 var matches = [];
 for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
  matches.push(arr[i].match(reg) ? arr[i].match(reg).length : 0);
 }
return matches; 
}
```

Then, just call it like this:

```
count(s,web);
```

And it will return `[4,1]`

This will take any array as the second parameter.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/amaan/5avCf/)

Answer (score 0):

- Use `.match` instead of `.indexOf`, then you'll get the number of
  matches directly
- Don't forget to declare your `i` var
- Put validation at the top, it's easier to understand

Rewrite:

```
var web = ["cat fat hat mat", "that the who"]
  , search = prompt('Search?')

function count(web, pattern){
    if (!pattern){
        return "Nothing entered!"
    }

    var result = []
      , exp = new RegExp(pattern, "g")

    for(var i = 0; i < web.length; i++){
        var matches = web[i].match(exp)
        result.push(matches ? matches.length : 0)
    }
    return result
}

alert(count(web, search))
```

**Most important**: avoid the line breaks before a block `{`.

This:

```
return
{
   x: 1
}
```

is equivalent to

```
return;
{
   x: 1
};
```

that is, `return undefined`.